# Is it secure serilog configuration as XML configuration instead of c# in the .netframework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I am using log4net in my app. As per client suggestions, we need upgrade logs to serilog instead of log4net. I have seen serilog configuration as c# level, XML and JSON.
Which configuration is secure?

Comment: Could you define "secure". There should be no sensitive information in serilog configuration.

Comment: The recent sonatype scan reported high security risk in log4net. If i use serilog with XML configuration any high security risk happen?